# submit button is not working in django form using crispy

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have a contact form in Django, and I use crispy in my template, but in both the Class base view and Function base view, my submit button is not working, and I have no errors.
here is my fbv code. I also tried it with cbv

my template is using jquery,bootstrap,moment.js

here is my code:

models.py

```
class ContactUs(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Full Name")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Email")
    message = models.TextField(verbose_name="Message")
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "contact us"
        verbose_name_plural = "Messages"
```

forms.py:

```py
    class CreateContactForm(forms.Form):
        fullname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Full Name"}),
                                   validators=[
                                       validators.MaxLengthValidator(150,
                                                                     "Your name should be less than 150 character")
                                   ],
                                   )
        email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Email address"}),
                                 validators=[
                                     validators.MaxLengthValidator(150,
                                                                   "Your email should be less than 150 character")
                                 ],
                                 )
        message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"placeholder": "Your Message"}))
```

views.py:

```py
     def contact_page(request):
       contact_form = CreateContactForm(request.POST or None)
       if contact_form.is_valid():
         fullname = contact_form.cleaned_data.get('fullname')
         email = contact_form.cleaned_data.get('email')
         message = contact_form.cleaned_data.get('message')
         ContactUs.objects.create(fullname=fullname, email=email, message=message, is_read=False)
         # todo : show user a success message
         contact_form = CreateContactForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {"contact_form": contact_form}
    return render(request, 'contact_page.html', context)
```

Template:

```html
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" data-toggle="validator" novalidate="true" method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-6">
      {{ contact_form.fullname|as_crispy_field }} {% for error in contact_form.fullname.errors %}
      <div class="help-block with-errors">{{ error }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-6">
      {{ contact_form.email|as_crispy_field }} {% for error in contact_form.email.errors %}
      <div class="help-block with-errors">{{ error }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-12">
      {{ contact_form.message|as_crispy_field }} {% for error in contact_form.message.errors %}
      <div class="help-block with-errors">{{ error }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-2 order-md-1 text-center text-md-left">
      <div id="validator-contact" class="hidden"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 order-1 order-md-2 text-right">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn"><i class="font-icon icon-send"></i> Send Message</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to either set the `action` in the `form` tag to send a post request to your `contact_page` view or make the button itself send a post request to the `contact_page` view

Comment: I don't understand  can you say what should i do exactly?

Comment: I'm assuming you have a url pointing towards the `contact_page` view. Let's just assume its called `contact-page`. Change `action=""` to `action="{% url 'contact-page' %}"`. This will make it actually send a request to the view.

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work and stills not working

Comment: @DilIsPickle It's fairly common to leave out the `action` attribute.  The form will submit back to the same view.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "save" to the submit button class.

Also your contact_page view does nothing after saving the contact data to the db. If you'll do a pop-up confirmation in JS you don't need to instantiate `contact_form` the second time. Or if you want to redirect the user:

```py
def contact_page(request):
    contact_form = CreateContactForm(request.POST or None)
    if contact_form.is_valid():
        fullname = contact_form.cleaned_data.get('fullname')
        email = contact_form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        message = contact_form.cleaned_data.get('message')
        ContactUs.objects.create(
            fullname=fullname,
            email=email,
            message=message,
            is_read=False
        )
        return redirect('some-view')
    context = {"contact_form": contact_form}
    return render(request, 'contact_page.html', context)
```